# Linear regulator LED driver starts flickering when powered on

Tags: led, led-driver

I'm using an [STCS1PUR](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stcs1.pdf) on my board. The schematic is the same as the datasheet suggests, except that the EN and PWM pins are tied to Vin, which should be correct if I don't need any control on the driver but just constant current.

The problem is when I power on the light. It will hold steady for a few seconds then it starts to flicker at a very low frequency, like 2-10 Hz.

I am using three CREE XQ-E LEDs in series driving around 400 mA. In theory it's way under the driver's maximum load. What causes the flickering?

[image]

Comment: What voltage are you using?  Do you have the exposed pad on the bottom connected to a large copper area as a heat sink?

Comment: Probe Vcc and drain pin.

Comment: @winny Vcc pin have minor voltage change, but Drain pin have around 3V difference when flickering

Comment: @JRE EP is connected to the copper pad at the BOT but I think you are right, I will try to stick a alumium heat sink at the back and see if it still flickers. I only use 12V to drive the circuit and under 24V it gets even worse.

Comment: A simple fix would be to use 4 or 5 LEDs. Then your forward voltages would sum to 8 or 10v and the regulator would only have to dissipate the last 2 or 4v. 24v isn't realistic, if you need that get a buck regulator rather than linear.

Comment: White led color? So with 12 V supply and ~ 3V @ 350 mA per LED you burn around 1.1 W in the die. Please show us your board, proper thermal design is a must like @Rohat told. I assume your 12 V supply is up to the task as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a thermal shutdown behaviour.

This is a linear regulator. So the excess power *(i.e. the difference of input and output voltages times the load current, P = (V<sub>in</sub> - V<sub>out</sub>) x I<sub>out</sub> = (12 - 9) x 0.36 = **1.1 W**)* will be dissipated by the chip. And this will cause the internal (junction) temperature increase.

Once the junction temperature reaches to 155 °C due to possible poor thermal design the regulator will shut itself down. After shutdown the junction will cool down, and once it reaches to a relatively safe-to-operate temperature it'll turn on again. This will repeat periodically.

You need to take thermal considerations into account. Without a proper heatsink (e.g. large enough copper pour with vias) this behaviour will be inevitable. Also you may want to decrease the input-to-output voltage difference (by increasing the number of series LEDs, for example) — the higher the difference the higher the losses.

Comment: He setup for 350 mA and if it are the white LEDs they have around 2.9 V drop so 8.7 V total and power die dissipation is only around 1.2 W - still enough that your hint on thermal design is fully correct.